# How to disable autofs client mount caching

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, samba

I have the following linux environment configuration 
Machine 1: Samba server

```
[share]
    comment = Data
    path = /share
    force create mode = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    force user = root
    force group = root
    writeable = Yes
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

Machine 2: mount point to machine 1 share folder, using autofs service. auto.app file content :

```
/store -fstype=cifs,cache=none,forcedirectio,noac ://machine1/share
```

Machine 3: mount point to machine 1 share folder, using autofs service. auto.app file content :

```
/store -fstype=cifs,cache=none,forcedirectio,noac ://machine1/share
```

The problem that I'm facing is that if i'm updating a file under /store folder on machine 2, it will take a couple of seconds(~5 seconds) for the changes to become available on /store folder under machine 3. I want the changes to become available right away on machine 3. I don't care about any performance implications.

It looks like a caching problem to me, but i couldn't find a way to disable this so far. What i've tried so far was to pass the **cache=none,forcedirectio,noac** parameters but no success.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but on RHEL 5.8, we got the caching disabled on a system level by `echo 0 > /proc/fs/cifs/LookupCacheEnabled`.

LookupCacheEnabled file has the CIFS coniguration for the no of seconds to wait before refreshing the cache. By setting the value to 0, you will disable the cache. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved the caching issue was to drop samba and install nfs